# How to create component that has HTMLAttributes as props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

I am using Typescript and Preact. I want to create a component that exposes all the props that a `<span/>` can have:

```
import { h, Component } from "preact";

export class MySpan extends Component<any, void> {
    render(props) {
        return <span {...props}></span>;

    }
}
```

However, the above example uses `any`, which is not really typesafe. Rather I want to expose the properties `span` has.

Answer (score 4):

In react I would do it this way:

```
export class MySpan extends React.Component<React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>, void>
{
    public render()
    {
        return <span {...this.props}/>;
    }
}
```

I do not have real experience with `preact` but taking into account their [preact.d.ts](https://github.com/developit/preact/blob/master/src/preact.d.ts), it should be something similar to:

```
import { h, Component } from "preact";

export class MySpan extends Component<JSX.HTMLAttributes, void> {
    render(props) {
        return <span {...props}></span>;

    }
}
```

Note that this will not be specific properties for span element but rather generic ones.

Comment: You can try this one: Component<JSX.HTMLAttributes & {children?:JSX.Element[]}, void>